# how do you issue select statment against the oracle table without double quotes around the column names

Tags: oracle

I need to connect to oracle table and issue a select stament. When I do this:

```
SELECT T."Node" as LPAR, to_char(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE),'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi') as DATETIME,T."MAX_Memory_Size_MB",T."MIN_Comp_Memory",T."AVG_Comp_Memory", T."MAX_Comp_Memory", T."MIN_Non_Comp_Memory", T."AVG_Non_Comp_Memory", "MAX_Non_Comp_Memory" FROM DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV T where t."Node" like 'server%'
```

it works, but the program I am using does not like double quotes around the column names e.g. T."Node".

I tried to rewrite this sql statment as below, but now I get invalid identifier.

Is there a way around this?

```
SELECT Node as LPAR, to_char(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp, TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE),'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi') as DATETIME,MAX_Memory_Size_MB, MIN_Comp_Memory,AVG_Comp_Memory, MAX_Comp_Memory, MIN_Non_Comp_Memory, AVG_Non_Comp_Memory, MAX_Non_Comp_Memory FROM DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV where Node like 'server%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first statement works, that indicates that you have created a case-sensitive column name.  If you do that, you will have to use double-quotes around the identifier and specify the case correctly every single time you refer to the column.  Creating a case-sensitive identifier is generally something that you should avoid at all costs.

If this is a new database object, the preferred solution would be to change the column name to be case-insensitive

```
ALTER TABLE DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV
  RENAME COLUMN "Node" TO Node;
```

Another option would be to create a view on top of the table that exposes case-insensitive identifiers and to query that view rather than the base table.  Of course, you'd also need to do that for all the other case-insensitive identifiers you reference in the query.

Comment: altering table is not option. I dont have any writes to modify the table etc. I can only issue select statments.

Comment: @user1471980 - Then you're stuck needing to use case-sensitive identifiers and you have to ensure that the identifiers are always enclosed in double quotes and cased correctly.  As you've discovered, not every tool can handle this which is one of the many reasons that case sensitive identifiers are strongly discouraged.

Comment: I just discovered a solution where I have to escape the double quotes. I'll go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks.